# web.xml: Request to url-pattern with wildcard timeouts

Tags: java, servlets, wildcard, web.xml, url-pattern

I am making a "blog-platform" where users can write articles, and I want each article to get its own URL. Therefore, I'd like every page with the URL `/blog/*` to be sent to the same Servlet.

I have tried using **web.xml** like this:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>BlogServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>package.BlogServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>BlogServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/blog/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>MainServlet</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

This doesn't work. `/blog` works, but `/blog/` and `/blog/any_string` only gives off a timeout after a while. What am I doing wrong? Is there any other way I could implement this, other than parameters?

Comment: What's the name of the `.war `file?

Comment: I haven't exported the project to .war yet, and I'm still running it locally in eclipse.

Comment: Can you give an example of the whole URL?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your request. The URL that works right now is localhost:8080/project/blog. I want localhost:8080/project/blog/myarticle to send a request to the same BlogServlet.

Comment: If the container cannot find a resource mapped to the request path, it returns a 404 response immediately (and not a timeout). Are you sure the problem is not your Servlet  itself?

Comment: The servlet works fine when requesting `/blog`. If you want to see the servlet code, I will provide it in a little while.